# loop php script in bash

Tags: php, linux, bash, cron

I need to run php cli every second in linux bash.
Below you can find my windows.bat file:

```
:loop
start /b pathTophp.exe pathTo\cycler.php
timeout /t 1
goto loop
```

Perhaps I can use cron and run this simple script every second but I assume minute is a least interval.

`#!/bin/bash
 php56 cycler.php`

As I know there is no goto in bash and I don't know bash at all. So how can I make this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are correct cron can only go to 1 minute interval, try this

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do 
 php56 cycler.php
 sleep 1
done
```

this will loop until you stop it with ctrl-c

Comment: Thanks, it works, and is sufficient for this only test project.